# Are inode limits by directory or by drive?

Tags: filesystems, inode

Are the inode limits on Linux by subdirectory or by the entire file system?  I use ububtu 64 bit server 9.10.

Can the inode limit be resolved by splitting files up into multiple sub directories if it's a directory limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inodes are the *nix representation of disk files. They are identified by a number, not by the path where they are in the directory structure. So the limit is across the whole file system, regardless of which hard link(s) (file entry you see in a directory) point(s) to the inode.

Comment: How would one see the remaining inodes on a file system?

Comment: Use `df -i` to get some statistics about inode usage in your filesystems.

Comment: this prints inode stats: df -hi

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is a limit to both.  I saw a video of a presentation by someone from YouTube who talked about the day they ran into the per-directory file limit on ext2.  Suddenly, nobody could upload to YouTube any more.  They had to deepen their directory tree.

According to this doc, the limit is somewhere around 10k-15k files: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/ext2.txt

Of course, the limit depends on what filesystem you are using.  I believe ReiserFS has much higher limits, for example.